Problema con Height en HTML Y CSS
Hola tengo un header ("cabecera") que tiene 60 px de height.  Metí adentro otro contenedor con 100% de height y adentro de ese una imagen (id = logocodoacodo ) ambos con 100% de height. El tema es que practicando quise cambiar la  altura del contenedor que tiene la imagen, de 100% a 60 px entendiendo que no debería existir ningún cambio ya que el 100% del contenedor padre son justamente 60 px. Sin embargo la foto se agrandó un poco y no entiendo por que. Dejé las clases de bootstrap por si tienen algo que ver pero no creo.  Las medidas de la foto son de 200 px de alto pero obviamente se ajusta al contenedor.
la versión de bootstrap es 5.2.1
HTML
<nav id="cabecera" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark px-5">

   <div href="#" id="tamanio-div-logo">
     <img src="images/codoacodo.png" alt="codo a codo logo" id="logocodoacodo">
   </div>  

CSS
#cabecera {

  height: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#tamanio-div-logo {
  height: 100%;
}

#logocodoacodo {
  height: 100%;
}





Confírmame que la imagen se agranda y no es que se mueve, sería bueno que agregaras una imagen de cada caso a tu pregunta. Además de indicar la versión de bootstrap

listo hecho ambas cosas

Primero aclarar que la clase navbar de bootstrap incluye padding y es un factor para el problema que tu describes.
Luego tú dices que:

El tema es que practicando quise cambiar la altura del contenedor que tiene la imagen, de 100% a 60px entendiendo que no debería existir ningún cambio ya que el 100% del contenedor padre son justamente 60px.

Esto no es siempre cierto, el box-sizing cambia este comportamiento, pero vamos por partes
La anatomía de una caja es:

Content area
Padding area
Border area
Margin area



box-sizing: content-box:  Al poner un height:60px estas diciendo que solo el Content area vale 60px

box-sizing: border-box: Este valor lo setea bootstrap para todos los elementos, Al poner un height:60px estas diciendo el conjunto de Content area, Padding area y Border area vale en total 60px


Lo otro que hay que tener muy en cuenta, es que cuando utilizamos porcentajes es relativo solo al Content area y NO a toda la dimensión de la caja
Con todo esto claro, ahora analicemos tu caso:
Boostrap te agrega:

box-sizing: border-box a todo
Un padding arriba y abajo de 8px para el nav#cabecera

Luego tú dices que nav#cabecera tiene un height: 60px; y como es box-sizing: border-box, esto quiere decir que los 60px incluyen el padding
Entonces:
Alto_Content_area = alto_caja - padding_arriba - padding_abajo
Alto_Content_area = 60 - 8 - 8 = 44px

Luego tu imagen que tiene height: 100%; mide 44px de alto, porque, repito el porcentaje es relativo al Content_area
Posteriormente tú dices que cambias a height: 60px; y se agranda la imagen. Bueno ahora es evidente 60px > 40px

Muchas gracias por tu solución. muy bien explicada. –
